# Apple Cover-flow effect using jQuery or other library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side-scripting

Does anyone know how to achieve the cover-flow effect using JavaScript to scroll through a bunch of images.  I'm not talking about the 3D rotating *itunes* cover-art, but the effect that happens when you hit the space bar in a folder of documents, allowing you to preview them in a *lightbox* fashion.

Comment: Do you mean Coverflow (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_Flow) or Quick look (http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/quicklook.html)?

Comment: The description is defiantly of Quick Look (not Cover Flow)..

Comment: @rickyduck Yep. Might have something to do with bad spelling an a spell checker.

Comment: Still, it turned out to have a great range of answers on Coverflow, even recent ones! 9/10, would search again.

Answer (score 72):

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

- is the best I ever found. 
  a true 'CoverFlow', highly configurable, cross-browser, very smooth action, has relections and supports scroll wheel + keyboard control. - has to be what your looking for!

Comment: Thank you zack, this is indeed the best of all coverflow libs I have seen in my evaluation!

Comment: This looks great, but I'm really turned off by the fact that it requires you to tinker with the DOM and as such can't possibly degrade gracefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. I found a few others, notably this one - http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/ - but ContentFlow is absolute the best bang for this buck.

Comment: Because this is manipulating height & width values & constantly listening to the mousemove event, this solution is very slow on mobile devices.  A more performance optimized solution would be to use css3 transitions... It's built to do this natively.  It wont work in ie6/7/8, but you could easily implement a graceful-degrade or polyfill to handle that.

Comment: Link is dead now in 2017 - can I find this elsewhere?

Comment: Oldest "full" link in the Wayback machine is from [April, 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160416154800/http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/), and the code is archived as "ContentFlow_1.0.2.zip" [on GitHub](https://github.com/noviggo/ofertautomotriz/tree/master/ofertautomotriz).

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if you're talking about Coverflow (scroll through images) or Quicklook (preview files in lightbox), try editing your question.

Here's some JS Coverflow implementations:

- [MooFlow - Coverflow for MooTools](http://www.outcut.de/MooFlow/example-ajax.html)
- [Coverflow in JS proof of concept](http://radnan.public.iastate.edu/coverflow/)
- [Coverflow using JS and CSS Transforms (Webkit only)](http://paulbakaus.com/?p=6&language=en)

Comment: A cross-browser implementation with mobile support, http://luwes.co/labs/js-cover-flow/

Comment: I can recommend @luwes implementation. Good to use and can also be used "offline", if you need to present something in HTML without an internet connection (as it was in my case the case).

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you want http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/

Answer (score 4):

I tried using the the Jack's Asylum cover flow but it wouldn't let me easily remove and re-add an entire coverflow. I eventually found http://finnrudolph.de/ImageFlow and not only is it more reliable, it's easier to hook into, uses less markup, and doesn't jitter when flipping through images. It's by far the best I've found, and I've tried several on this page.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Apple style Gallery Slider over at 
http://www.jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/ which uses jQuery and the UI.

Answer (score 2):

[jCoverflip](http://www.jcoverflip.com) was just released and is very customizable.

Answer (score 2):

colorbox has such amazing features..loving it.
Also like this one http://www.webappers.com/2008/03/05/galleria-simple-but-nice-jquery-image-gallery/

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

"[Create an Apple Itunes-like banner rotator/slideshow with jQuery](http://youhack.me/2011/08/11/create-an-itunes-like-banner-rotatorslideshow-with-jquery/)" is an article explaining how you can make such effect using jQuery.

You can also view the
[live demo](http://youhack.me/demo/Apple%20itunes%20banner%20rotator/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try Jquery Interface Elements here - http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/carousel

Here's a sample.  http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/carousel.html

I looked around for a Jquery image carousel a few months ago and didn't find a good one so I gave up.  This one was the best I could find.

Answer (score 1):

Check out momoflow: http://flow.momolog.info
True coverflow effect, and performant on Webkit (Safari and Chrome) and Opera, ok on Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you all know, xFlow! has had some major work done on it and is vastly improved.

Go to http://xflow.pwhitrow.com for more info and the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

i am currently working on this and planning on releasing it as a jQuery-ui plugin.

-> http://coulisse.luvdasun.com/

please let me know if you are interested and what you are hoping to see in such a plugin.

gr

Answer (score 0):

> the effect that happens when you hit the space bar in a folder of
>   documents, allowing you to preview them in a lightbox fashion

Looks like a classic lightbox plugin is needed. This is my favorite jQuery lightbox plugin: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/. It's easy to customize, etc.

Answer (score -1):

This one looks really promising, and closer to the actual Apple coverflow effect than the other examples:

[blarnee.com/projects/cflow](http://www.blarnee.com/projects/cflow/)

Comment: ...except that it crashes (at least on IE)

Comment: ...and on chrome it does nowt