# Creating Photo-Flow (itune-like navigation) dynamically - Any Free or Easy way to do this?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm wondering if there is a free script or easy tutorial on how to make photo-flow like the top of [this](http://www.cvcf.com/sermons/) website.

It is similar to how itunes album navigation works.

So far, all I found is [this non-free photo flow](http://www.flashloaded.com/flashcomponents/photoflow/). I was wondering if this can be done without paying any money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to search for is 'cover flow'. It's very easy to build yourself using pv3d - there's a tutorial here: http://labs.blitzagency.com/?p=314 and some flex components here: http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/11/03/coverflow-flex-component/.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to CS4 and use the built-in 3D effects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at this widget: Smile Widgets - Runway

**simile-widgets.org/runway**

It's released under the BSD license.

The other widgets they have are also very interesting! Smile Widgets

**simile-widgets.org**

From their website:

> This is an open-source “spin-off” from
>   the Simile project at MIT. Here we
>   offer free, open-source web widgets,
>   mostly for data visualizations. They
>   are maintained and improved over time
>   by a community of open-source
>   developers.

Answer (score 0):

You could abandon Flash and achieve the Cover Flow effect using JavaScript. See [Apple Cover-flow effect using jQuery or other library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207/apple-cover-flow-effect-using-jquery-or-other-library).

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I used one called MooFlow for a site I worked on:

http://www.ownnzproperty.co.nz/

http://www.outcut.de/MooFlow/MooFlow.html

Seemed pretty good to me

Requires the Mootools Javascript framework