# Cover flow like jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

Anyone knows that any jQuery plugins or to build something similar to image effect/gallery like Apple OSX Finder - Cover Flow?

Comment: No, but I imagine that with the proper properties being modified it's a matter of trigonometry. (Distance from the center modifies the angle of the image.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apple Cover-flow effect using jQuery or other library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207/apple-cover-flow-effect-using-jquery-or-other-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://www.outcut.de/MooFlow/