# Coverflow with Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coverflow

It been a long time that im searching on how can i create my own Coverflow effect with Javascript or Jquery.
So if any one have an idea or can give a something releated with that, it will be great.

Thnx

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207/apple-cover-flow-effect-using-jquery-or-other-library

Answer (score 1):

Try [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/).

Comment: but what i want, its an explanation of how to create your own coverflow.
i worked arround for a while, and i was able to create a circle and even an ellipse by position images on borders, but that was on 2D.

Comment: and now i'm not sure if it was the good way for creating the coverflow. so if you have an explanation of how to begin or if anyone know something on the techniques or mathematicals formula to doing that, it will be appreciated to share it.

thnx in advance