# Can you advise jquery slider as pictured on screen?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, 3d, slider, carousel

Wasted too much time trying too find smth like on screen. Has anybody used smth like this? [image]

Comment: this is nothing to do with jquery the type of effect you are looking is coverflow you can create using the core CSS3 and HTML. But seems you want to create using js, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207/apple-cover-flow-effect-using-jquery-or-other-library 
this might be help otherwise google coverflow using css effect.

Comment: Thanx so much, it is very useful comment!